# Generic encryption & decryption module - question regarding password stretching & salt

Tags: pbkdf-2, salt, password-based-encryption

We want to implement an encryption / decryption module that we want to provide to different internal components of our system (internal library for internal components).

The component will provide (authenticated) Encryption & Decryption based on state-of-the art algorithms (AES-GCM-256).

Furthermore we have a Password stretching function based on PBKDF2 which generates the "cipherKey" that can be used with the Encrypt & Decrypt routines.

So the public functions would look like this:

- func Encrypt(plaintext, cipherKey) (ciphertext)
- func Decrypt(ciphertext, cipherKey) (plaintext)
- func CipherKeyFromPassword(password) (cipherKey)

Our CipherKeyFromPassword routine internally uses the PBKDF2 algorithm for key-stretching. As mentioned algorithm requires a salt, we wondered, if it would provide more security (or even if it would be absolutely mandatory) to not use a fixed salt but instead use a randomly-generated / user-input salt per call. In that case, the user would need to remember the salt to be able to re-generate the same cipherKey.

So the main question is whether I could use the same salt inside the CipherKeyFromPassword routine or if I have to make it configurable / random to avoid any potential attacks (rainbow tables, dictionary, ...)?

Comment: Not sure I'd call AES-GCM 'state-of-the-art' and PBKDF2 certainly isn't (ideally switch to Argon2). The salt shouldn't be fixed; it should be randomly generated each time. It technically could be user provided or non-random as long as it's unique, but that's generally not recommended. The salt is typically stored with the ciphertext rather than anybody having to remember it, which is generally limited to deterministic password managers.

Comment: Personally I would be against doing any of this kind of stuff. Centralizing on a specific encryption class where you choose the algorithms beforehand is a management nightmare. Encryption should be use-case specific. For instance: you're making passwords mandatory, while it is better to use keys directly where possible. Choosing use case specific higher level protocols usually makes more sense. If you're going to do anyway: please at least describe your protocol and use some kind of versioning number, or you'll be stuck with your choice forever.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - to be honest that's what I want to do as well just to make sure that we are not bound to the chosen algorithm forever. But regardless of that - given that we use a KDF function for key stretching that requires a salt ... how would you handle the salt?

Comment: I'd use a 128 bit random salt and include it with the ciphertext. You might want to think about including a version number or iteration count as well in case you want to upgrade to a higher value, because that's more likely to be an issue than the key size. Beware that if the attacker has hold of an old ciphertext that upgrading the iteration count may be moot.

Comment: Thanks guys. We'll change the component and make it right from the start to avoid any potential API version changes in the future.

What parameters would you make configurable for the Encryption & Decryption & the KDF functions to have a slim library however be as "future-proof" as possible (e.g. algorithm, key-size, iteration count, hash-algorithm used for kdf, ....).